# Can I disable a asp.net web api route in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I need to disable a route temporarily in an asp.net webapi app and I cannot do compile and do another deploy.

Can I just a disable a asp.net web api route in web.config?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can disable a specific route in web.config. Normally if you want to disable a route, you can use `IgnoreRoute`, or just remove the route in `WebApiConfig.cs` or `Global.asax` file wherever the route exists.

Since you only want to do it in web.config without doing compile and another deploy, I can only think about two ways.

1) Use URL Rewriting

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="diableRoute" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="api/YourWebApiController" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="Error/NotFound" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This result will return the 404 Error page.

2) Setting authorization rules

```
 <location path="api/YourWebApiController">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This result will return to the login page, because the access to the web api route is denied.

You can customize either one to your need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another solution is to configure request filtering rule in IIS.

Comment: Is it possible to enable only certain path and deny all the rest of the api using the <location> method in the web.config ?

Comment: The rewrite rule needs to be in  `<configuration><system.webServer><rewrite>` . That was missing for me and I got a `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`